# How to update Status as Active or Inactive on Button click in ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

> My question is how can I `Activate` or `InActivate` users by clicking the button. If I clicked InActivate, the text on the button should be changed to Activate. I searched on google but I didn't get the solution:

This is Example Code For Asp.net C# code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnStatus" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ModuleID") %>'
     CssClass="imagelink" OnClick="lbtnStatus_Click"><span class='label <%#Eval("Status").ToString()=="Y"?"label-success":"label-danger"%>'><%#Eval("Status").ToString()=="Y"?"Active":"Inactive"%></span></asp:LinkButton>
```

How can I change the c# code to MVC Code any Idea?

Comment: you can use two button and you can hide and show functionality according to status

Comment: When i click on active button it shows Inactive red color font. and When i click on inactive button it shows active green color font. @M.Y.Mnu

Comment: then what you want to do ?

Comment: How to change that code to mvc? any idea @M.Y.Mnu

Comment: hide and show function directly get value from database then display. i want to change manually button click table rows @M.Y.Mnu

Answer (score 1):

You should perform it in client side. Try something like that;

```
$("#lbtnStatus").click(function() {
    var value = $("#lbtnStatus span").text();
    if(value == "Inactive")
    {
        $(this).html("<span class='label-success'>Active</span>");
    } else if(value == "Active")
    {
        $(this).html("<span class='label-danger'>Inactive</span>");
    }
});
```

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("EditModules", "Account"),new{id= item.Status} '></a>

Comment: Put the code snippet in your view inside these tags "<script></script>". You should investigate Javascript /JQuery firstly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following way in client side with the help of jQuery.

```
<button type="button" id="lbtnStatus"><span class="label-success">Active</span></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lbtnStatus').click(function () {
            if ($(this).find('span').hasClass("label-success"))
                $(this).find('span').removeClass("label-success").addClass("label-danger").text("InActive");
            else
                $(this).find('span').removeClass("label-danger").addClass("label-success").text("Active");
        });
    });
</script>
```